# Simplifying vector expressions

Tags: manipulate

I have some code that calculates Jacobians, but the results contain terms that should simplify or cancel out, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. My code looks like

```
Outer[D,{r,u.u},{r,u}]
```

which produces output:

```
{{1,0},{0,1.u+u.1}}
```

I would like to Mathematica to combine the `1.u+u.1` terms, but I'm not sure what to do. I should mention that `u` is supposed to be a vector variable, but I'm not explicitly telling Mathematica that, currently.

Comment: the fundamental problem is that mathematica does not recognize `u` as a vector , and there is unfortuantely no simple work around.  You should look at this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html but before going too deep be aware only certain functions recognize symbolic vector concepts (`D` in particular does not )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean you want the output to be?

```
t[e_] := e /. Plus[Dot[1, x_], Dot[x_, 1]] :> 2 x
f[x_, y_] := Simplify[D[x, y], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
Outer[f, {r, u.u}, {r, u}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have another related issue. At one point, I do a substitution which results in terms like

    r^2 u.u-(r u).(r u)
which should cancel, but they don't. How can I make Mathematica simplify terms like this?

Comment: @TrumanEllis it looks you need another transformation rule. May be post separate question with an example to use for input to duplicate the output and may be someone can then help better.

Answer (score 0):

another approach that handles this example:

```
 Clear[dv, x, r]
 dv[Dot[x_, x_], x_] := 2 x
 dv[x_, y_] := D[x, y]
 Outer[dv, {r, u.u}, {r, u}]
```

> {{1, 0}, {0, 2 u}}